# Connect Raspberry pi3 to Samsung smart TV through wifi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, display, wireless

I am doing a project now for my office which I want to connect a Raspberry pi 3 to Samsung smart TV through wireless. I want to to use the TV like a computer monitor wireless.

Raspbian is installed & updated. SSH & VNC enabled along with XRDP & I can access it with Putty, Windows remote desktop connection & VNC.

Could someone please help me in telling me how to connect to the TV through WiFi.

My requirement is, I want to connect multiple Samsung smart TV to this Raspberry.

Comment: I assume you want to be able to control the TV via the local WIFI connection,

I know that the Node-Red IDE has some nodes to control some Samsung TV. There might be software libraries for your favorite language possibly available on GitHub

Comment: I want to to use the TV like a computer monitor wireless.